# Return from async NSOpenPanel

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can this function be re-written to return the variable "files"? I'm completely unfamiliar with async and completion handlers, so I wasn't able to use existing answers as a starting point. It's a simple function that returns the files from a user-selected directory.

```
func readFolder() {

    let dialog = NSOpenPanel()
    dialog.prompt = "Choose"
    dialog.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    dialog.canChooseDirectories = true
    dialog.canCreateDirectories = true
    dialog.canChooseFiles = false
    dialog.showsResizeIndicator = true
    dialog.showsHiddenFiles = false
    dialog.begin {
        
        (result) -> Void in if result == .OK {
            
            let directory = dialog.url!
            
            do {
                var files = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(
                    at: directory,
                    includingPropertiesForKeys: nil
                )
            } catch {
                NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "I'm completely unfamiliar with async and completion handlers" Then get familiar with them. You cannot return anything from an async operation. Start here and read this set of three articles: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: I understand the concept of asynchronous. What I don't understand is how we're supposed to work with asynchronous functions. If you can't return anything, what's the point of attempting to read directories/files?

Comment: That's what the completion handler is for. Please _read_ the three articles starting at the one I linked you to. It builds up this concept clearly and slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with your question when you mentioned "completion handlers." With async functions, you aren't going to actually return the value directly, but rather through a function that you provide as a completion handler. This takes some getting-used-to to restructure the way you think of some of your code, but is a great concept to become familiar with.

Code first, then explanation:

```
func doSomethingThatRequiresFiles() {
    readFolder { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let files):
            print(files)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func readFolder(completion: @escaping (Result<[URL],Error>) -> Void) {
    
    let dialog = NSOpenPanel()
    dialog.prompt = "Choose"
    dialog.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    dialog.canChooseDirectories = true
    dialog.canCreateDirectories = true
    dialog.canChooseFiles = false
    dialog.showsResizeIndicator = true
    dialog.showsHiddenFiles = false
    dialog.begin { (result) -> Void in
        if result == .OK {
            guard let directory = dialog.url else {
                assertionFailure("Not a directory")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let files = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(
                    at: directory,
                    includingPropertiesForKeys: nil
                )
                completion(.success(files))
            } catch {
                NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        } else {
            //handle cancelled case
        }
    }
}
```

The first function (`doSomethingThatRequiresFiles` ) is an example of a place in your code where you want to deal with files. You'll see there's a switch statement that lets you handle either success or failure. You can see that the line `print(files)` is where you would put your code that needs to deal with the files somehow.

In the `readFolder` function, there's now a parameter (`completion`) gets a `Result` type -- it can either be an array of `URL`s or an `Error`. Read more about `Result`: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/161/how-to-use-result-in-swift

And detail about why `@escaping` is used: https://www.donnywals.com/what-is-escaping-in-swift/

Inside the `dialog.begin`, you can see that `completion` gets called with either the list of files or the error.

---

Using async functions will be a familiar pattern when working with the filesystem (in particular if you have to deal with the iCloud APIs) and certainly with networking, where basically everything is asynchronous. It's also a good pattern to be familiar with in situations (like this one) where you're waiting for a UI interaction.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation! Marking as solution. I think this will be super helpful starting point for others as well.